# Economics and Euclidean geometry

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for economics papers which use concepts, techniques and theorems from geometry. I am mainly interested in Euclidean geometry, the kind of material that is taught on high-schools (e.g. proving theorems about triangles, squares, circles, etc.). But, other kinds of geometry are also interesting.

I looked at some papers about land economics, thinking that it geometry can be useful there (after all, the word "geometry" means "measurement of land"). But, the papers I found used mostly advanced measure theory and topology. I am looking for more basic geometric methods.

Comment: There is an academic economist from Cyprus that has mapped basic aspects of Euclidean Geometry to some of the foundations of Economics theory. For the moment I cannot remember a specific reference but I will look it up.

Comment: There is a theory of spatial voting with Euclidean preferences. See [here](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/43893/1/a%20notion%20of%20equilibrium.pdf) for the paper that started it all. Some of the literature gets rathert echnical though.

Comment: There a paper by Lee Smolin (a physicist) that applies gauge theory to economics; gauge theory is geometric, but its advanced geometry, so doesn't fit the 'basic geometric methods' requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another example is [Economies with Public Goods: An Elementary Geometric Exposition](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1097-3923.00006/abstract) by William Thomson, which relies extensively on the geometry of equilateral triangles.

In general, William Thomson is known for making a heavy and interesting usage of geometry in his papers. See for instance a recent working paper of his : [Compromising between the proportional and constrained equal awards rules](http://rcer.econ.rochester.edu/RCERPAPERS/rcer_584.pdf) (although this one might be further from basic high-school euclidean geometry than what you're looking for).

Other somewhat similar examples include papers relying on the geometry of simplices. An example I came across recently is

- [A graphical analysis of some basic results in social choice,  Estelle Cantillon and Antonio Rangel, Social Choice and Welfare Vol. 19, No. 3 (2002), pp. 587-611](http://www.jstor.org.proxy.library.vanderbilt.edu/stable/41106883?seq=3#page_scan_tab_contents)

but there are many others, starting with the exposition of the expected utility theorem in Mas-Collel, Whinston and Green.

I am also tempted to point at the following recent paper, although it definitely uses geometric tools which go far beyond high-school euclidean geometry:

- [A Geometric Approach to Mechanism Design,   Jacob K. Goeree and  Alexey I. Kushnir Carnegie Mellon University Tepper Business School, 2013,  University of Zurich Department of Economics Working Paper No. 56](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1974922)

I don't have a specific paper for it (any intro to econ textbook would do), but I would also add the classical graphical measure of consumer and producer surpluses in ECON 101. (Especially for linear demand and consumer curves where is simplifies to measuring the area of a triangle. Can't do much more "measurement of land" than that)

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE 19-9-2017**

I just received word from the author that the book is now freely downloadable **in English**, [**at this link**](https://www.centralbank.cy/en/publications/books/euclidean-economics-a-mathematical-method-for-construction-and-application-of-economics-models).

---

Got it. I remember browsing the pages of this book. But it was in Greek, and it does not appear to have been published also in English:

**[Euclidean Economics: A Mathematical Method for Construction and Application of Economics Models](http://www.centralbank.gov.cy/nqcontent.cfm?a_id=12483&lang=en)**

> "*The book establishes that economics can be studied and utilised on
>   the basis of a minimum of fundamental hypotheses and the general laws
>   of mathematics. Starting from 12 major propositions, it proves that
>   closed exchange networks are replicated by systems of 2n first-order
>   non-homogeneous linear differential equations, which simulate
>   household, business, bank and government receipts and payments. Such
>   networks are defined in the (R2n, t) vector space, where n is the
>   number of sectors or markets and countries or currencies, while t is
>   the elapsed time. Uniqueness, stability and controllability of the
>   steady state as well as takings and outgoings are functions of
>   behaviour coefficients and policy parameters. Annual sales of
>   services, products and securities divided by average salaries, prices
>   and values yield the man hours, output items and liquidity units
>   traded. Demanded quantities do not coincide with available quantities.
>   Potential inflation or deflation is proportional to the weighted
>   deficit or surplus of market goods. Digital animation of the
>   endogenous variables is possible on the basis of historical, projected
>   or hypothetical data about the exogenous variables.*"

Author: **Sophocles Michaelides**
Language: Greek
Publisher: Mesogios Publications – Ellinika Grammata
ISBN: 9963-9176-0-7
Year: 2006

The summary does not state it clearly, but the "12 major propositions" are Euclidean, as I recall.

Comment: Wow this is really cool.

Answer (score 2):

Harry Johnson frequently applied euclidean geometry to trade theory and growth theory.  Have a look at his many papers and books.   For a more or less randomly chosen starting point, try his "Trade and Growth:  A Geometrical Exposition".

Answer (score 2):

There are some papers of Stefan Behringer from University of Bonn.

[Optimal Harvesting of a Spatial Renewable Resource](http://www.stefanbehringer.com/1219997.pdf) published in Journal of Economic Dynamics and Control

As the title indicates, there is a geometrical application, at least there is the notion of space.

Another paper that I remember is "Spatial dynamics and convergence: the spatial AK model" by Boucekkine et al. published in Journal of Economic Theory.

I think you can reach another strand of literature on space and mainly on geometric technics used in economics.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two problems (not papers, though the results are probably used in many papers)

1. In the case of a three asset [Markowitz portfolio optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_portfolio_theory) the feasible set of portfolios in $\mu$ / $\sigma$ space can be shown to be an ellipse.
2. When a [demand curve is a straight line the marginal revenue curve bisects the demand curve](http://www.economics.utoronto.ca/jfloyd/modules/eltr.html).

Answer (score 1):

One random example is this paper which uses similar triangles in the analysis of tax burdens. I think at least that bit of the paper (section 2) could be used in the high school context:

Hines, Hlinko, & Lubke (1995). "From each according to his surplus: Equi-proportionate sharing of commodity tax burdens" ([ScienceDirect link, gated](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/004727279401489B))